# Error al acceder a elementos de array de objetos creado dinámicamente

Tags: c++

Tengo esta clase (pongo también las implementaciones de Punto.cpp para ahorrar espacio) :

```
class Punto {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Punto();
    ~Punto();
    Punto(int _x, int _y) { x = _x; y = _y;}

    int GetX() { return x; }
    int GetY() { return y; }
    void SetX(int i) { x = i; }
    void SetY(int j) { y = j; }
};
```

Y esta otra :

```
class Barco{

private:
    int  partes;
    char orientacion;
    Punto* coordenadas;
public:
    Barco();
    Barco(int x, int y, int _partes, char cardinal);
    ~Barco();

    int  GetCoordenadaX(int i);
    int  GetCoordenadaY(int i);
    int  GetPartes();
    char GetOrientacion();
    void SetX();
    void SetY();
};
```

cuyo constructor es

```
Barco::Barco(int x, int y, int _partes, char cardinal)
{
    partes = _partes;
    orientacion = cardinal;
    coordenadas = new Punto[partes];
   for(int i = 0; i < partes; i++)
   {
      if(i == 0)
      {
          coordenadas[i].SetX(x);
          coordenadas[i].SetY(y);
      }
      else
      {
          switch(orientacion)
          {
          case 'N': // Orientación Norte
          { 
             coordenadas[i].SetX(x);
             coordenadas[i].SetY(y - i);
          }
          break;
          case 'S': // Orientación Sur
          {
             coordenadas[i].SetX(x);
             coordenadas[i].SetY(y + i);
          }
          break;
          case 'E': // Orientación Este
          {
             coordenadas[i].SetX(x + i);
             coordenadas[i].SetY(y);
          }
          break;
          case 'O': // Orientación Oeste
          {
             coordenadas[i].SetX(x - i);
             coordenadas[i].SetY(y);
          }
          break;
          } // Fin switch
      }
  }
```

y las funciones que devuelven las coordenadas son

```
GetCoordenadaX(int i) { return coordenadas[i].GetX(); }
GetCoordenadaY(int i) { return coordenadas[i].GetY(); }
```

Lo que quiero es crear un array dinámico de elementos "Punto" que almacenen
tantas coordenadas x, e y como número de partes tenga cada objeto "Barco"
(no he puesto el destructor de la clase "Barco" pero borro el array en él ;))
Pero si creo un array objetos "Barco" e intento recuperar las coordenadas de
sus elementos el programa se rompe con la famosa "segmentation fault" y la verdad
que no entiendo por qué. Pensaba que accedía bien a los elementos aunque es evidente que no.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que intento :

```
Barco barcos[3];
barcos[0] = Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S');
barcos[1] = Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E');
barcos[2] = Barco(2, 2, 3, 'S');

std::cout << " Barco[0].x = " << barcos[0].GetCoordenadaX(0) << "\n";
std::cout << " Barco[0].y = " << barcos[0].GetCoordenadaY(0) << "\n";
std::cout << " Barco[1].x = " << barcos[1].GetCoordenadaX(0) << "\n";-> ERROR "SEGMENTATION FAULT "
std::cout << " Barco[1].y = " << barcos[1].GetCoordenadaY(0) << "\n";
std::cout << " Barco[1].x = " << barcos[1].GetCoordenadaX(1) << "\n";
std::cout << " Barco[1].y = " << barcos[1].GetCoordenadaY(1) << "\n";
```

Si alguien tiene un momento y le pude echar un vistazo se lo agradecería enormemente. Se que debe ser una tontería, pero no logro verlo.
Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Barco barcos[3]; // (1)
barcos[0] = Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S'); // (2)
barcos[1] = Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E'); // (2)
barcos[2] = Barco(2, 2, 3, 'S'); // (2)
```

En el siguiente código sucede lo siguiente:

1. Creas 3 elementos de tipo barco
2. Sustituyes un elemento del array por un elemento creado para la ocasión

¿Problema?

En (2) se crea un objeto de tipo `Barco`, después se llama al operador de asignación que copia el contenido de dicho objeto en la posición correspondiente del array y después se llama al destructor del objeto que se acaba de crear. Los puntos calientes son los dos últimos:

- Al copiar un objeto en otro estás copiando el puntero interno `coordenadas`
- Al destruir el objeto temporal se está haciendo un delete de `coordenadas` (puntero compartido por dos objetos). A partir de este momento cualquier acceso a dicho puntero puede provocar un error.

¿Soluciones? Hay varias pero te pongo un par de ellas:

1. Usar punteros dobles: Así ya no se hacen copias de los objetos y no se comparten los punteros

   ```
   Barco *barcos[3];
   barcos[0] = new Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S');
   barcos[1] = new Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E');
   barcos[2] = new Barco(2, 2, 3, 'S');

   // ...

   for( int i=0; i<3; i++ ) 
     delete barcos[i];
   ```

   Aunque esto quedaría más limpio si usamos contenedores de la STL... si el número de elementos **siempre** va a ser tres te recomendaría `std::array`, en caso contrario, `std::vector` (su uso en este caso va a ser muy similar):

   ```
   std::array<Barco*,3> barcos;
   barcos[0] = new Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S');
   barcos[1] = new Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E');
   barcos[2] = new Barco(2, 2, 3, 'S');

   // ...

   for( int i=0; i<barcos.size(); i++ ) 
     delete barcos[i];
   ```
2. Usar *sintaxis move* (C++11 y superior). En este caso basta con *transferir* el contenido del objeto temporal al array en vez de simplemente copiar los datos:

   ```
   class Barco
   {
   public:
     Barco& operator=( Barco&& otro)
     {
       std::swap(partes,otro.partes);
       std::swap(orientacion,otro.orientacion);
       std::swap(coordenadas,otro.coordenadas);
       return *this;
     }
   };
   ```

   Y ahora lo aplicamos:

   ```
   Barco barcos[3];
   barcos[0] = Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S');
   barcos[1] = Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E');
   barcos[2] = Barco(2, 2, 3, 'S');
   ```

   Vaya, no hay que nacer nada para que funcione... `Barco(...)` es un *rvalue* y, en consecuencia, se llama automáticamente al operador de asignación que hemos creado.
3. Usa listas de inicialización

   ```
   // C++11 en adelante
   Barco barcos[3] = { {0, 0, 1, 'S'}, {1, 1, 2, 'E'}, {2, 2, 3, 'S'} };

   //versiones anteriores
   Barco barcos[3] = { Barco(0, 0, 1, 'S'), Barco(1, 1, 2, 'E'), Barco( 2, 2, 3, 'S') };
   ```
4. Reimplementa el operador de asignación para que no copie el puntero sino que lo duplique:

   ```
   class Barco
   {
   public:
     Barco& operator=( Barco const& otro)
     {
       partes = otro.partes;
       orientacion = otro.orientacion;

       delete[] coordenadas;
       coordenadas = new Punto[partes];
       for( int i=0; i<partes; i++ )
         coordenadas[i] = otro.coordenadas[i];

       return *this;
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: @eferionLa verdad es que había probado a usar también `std::vector` pero **no** de punteros, así que tampoco funcionaba. Me encantan todas las propuestas, no se con cual quedarme :). Creo que voy a probar la 2 y la 4 ;).

Comment: Y si te lo había dicho ya, lo repito y si no ahí queda : ojalá algún día llegue a saber la mitad de lo que sabeis tú y los sabios de este foro :). Mil gracias.